# How do I access Xcode crash logs when attempting to "Validate App" or "Distribute App"?

Tags: xcode, testflight, crash-log

I'm trying to submit a build to TestFlight. I created an archive by choosing "Generic iOS Device" Product > Archive. It then opened up the Window > Organizer.

There I'm presented with two options:

1. Distribute App
2. Validate App

If I choose Validate App, Xcode crashes immediately, and I can't see any error message. If I choose Distribute App > iOS App Store > Upload, it says "analyzing signature" and crashes immediately again (no error message).

If I try to Validate a different app, it succeeds. Thus there is something wrong with the set up of this project. However, because it instantly crashes and doesn't show an error message, I can't know what that is in order to resolve it.

Is there a way to view crash logs anywhere so I have a better understanding as to how to fix this problem?

I tried running on Xcode 10.1 and Xcode 10.2 beta 4. Both have the same behavior.

Comment: Were you able to find the `.crash` logs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Method #1:

You can check all crash logs from the `Console` app

- > Applications > Utilities > Console

or

- > Spotlight Search > Console

Click on `User Reports` in the sidebar and open the crash logs starting with the `Xcode`

---

#### Method #2:

The actual files are located here:

> ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/

- Paste this in `Finder > Go > Go to Folder`

Comment: It just shows a generic error message that is non-actionable. You could open up a Technical Support Incident to resolve with Apple.

Comment: @Senseful Yeah, but atleast it will give some hints like `Crashed Thread`, `Exception Note`, `Termination Reason`

Comment: The Apple TSI ticket came back with the following action items: (1) I was incorrectly including Pods frameworks that weren't proper dynamic libraries. Since they were set up as static libraries, I could actually remove them and it still built fine, since they were technically duplicates. (2) When I used `xcodebuild` to output frameworks, I forgot to specify `-configuration Release`, and needed to make sure to not import .dSYM files. (3) You cannot upload a binary that uses `lipo` to make fat binaries. You must remove the simulator architectures (e.g. via lipo) before uploading.

Comment: @Senseful Good thing you got clarity on this. However, Xcode should not be crashing on this. Hope you filed a bug report. Anyways, thanks for the follow up, I think you should also put this up as an answer.